# ActionController::UnknownFormat when sending plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm riding Rail4 and trying to send some plain text down with a GET request:

```
def get_text
  respond_to do |format|
    format.text { render :text => "huh" }
  end
end
```

But I end up with `ActionController::UnknownFormat` which I have frustrating discovered is Rails' funny way of saying 406 not acceptable.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was expecting format like json and xml but you have given text which is not a format.

```
def get_text
  render :text => "huh"
end
```

You can just simply send text like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
respond_to :text

def get_text
  respond_with |format|
     format.text { render text: "huh" }
  end
end
```